# Can't get a sensible result with libreplaygain.so and numpy

Tags: python, numpy, ctypes

I've been trying over and over again to use `libreplaygain.so` (`ReplayGain` is an algorithm for calculating loudness of audio. ) from python, passing it data from an audio file. Here is [the header file](http://sourcecodebrowser.com/libreplaygain/1.0~r412/gain__analysis_8h_source.html) of libreplaygain. I don't understand much about `ctypes` nor C in general, so I'm hoping it could be a problem of me being stupid, and very obvious for somebody else! Here is the script I am using :

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import wavfile
import ctypes
replaygain = ctypes.CDLL('libreplaygain.so')


def calculate_replaygain(samples, frame_rate=44100):
    """
    inspired from https://github.com/vontrapp/replaygain
    """
    replaygain.gain_init_analysis(frame_rate)
    block_size = 10000
    channel_count = samples.shape[1]
    i = 0
    samples = samples.astype(np.float64)

    while i * block_size < samples.shape[0]:
        channel_left = samples[i*block_size:(i+1)*block_size,0]
        channel_right = samples[i*block_size:(i+1)*block_size,1]

        samples_p_left = channel_left.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))
        samples_p_right = channel_right.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))

        replaygain.gain_analyze_samples(samples_p_left, samples_p_right, channel_left.shape[0], channel_count)
        i += 1

    return replaygain.gain_get_chapter()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    frame_rate, samples = wavfile.read('directions.wav')
    samples = samples.astype(np.float64) / 2**15
    gain = calculate_replaygain(samples, frame_rate=frame_rate)
    print "Recommended gain: %f dB" % gain
    gain = calculate_replaygain(np.random.random((441000, 2)) * 2 - 1, frame_rate=44100)
    print "Recommended gain: %f dB" % gain
```

The script runs, but I cannot get the same value as with the command line tool `replaygain`. In fact I always get `80.0`. To try you can replace 'directions.wav' with any sound file ... and compare the result with the result of the command `replaygain <soundfile.wav>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gain_get_chapter()` returns a `double`, but [the ctypes docs say](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#return-types) "By default functions are assumed to return the C int type." You should do something like

```
replaygain.gain_get_chapter.restype = ctypes.c_double
```

You should also check the return values of `gain_init_analysis` and `gain_analyze_samples`; if those aren't both 1, something else is going wrong. (Those actually are ints, so you shouldn't have to do anything else there.)

Comment: Oho ! Now with `gain_get_chapter.restype = ctypes.c_double` the result is different! And it changes with different files :) unfortunately it is still different than what the command line tool gives me. But that's definitely an improvement! Thanks!

Comment: Are the results 1 from the other functions? As a basic sanity check, do the results at all correlate with what the command line tool gives (e.g. lower gain for louder files)? Also, are you sure the command-line tool is using the same block size, and that `2**15` is the right amount to normalize by?

Comment: Results from the other functions are 1. Essentially this is the problem : I have no idea what data the program expects. Usually sound is handled either as unsigned 16-bits ints or floats in the interval [-1.0, 1[ so that's what I am using here it returns 0.000. I have tried without normalizing (scipy returns values in [-2**15, 2**15[), and I get 65.57. The commandline tool gives -3.53. I will try to read the C code (Brrrrr :(

Comment: Ok the values seem to correlate losely to the command line tool. I think it is just a problem of normalization. Thanks for the solution!